# What does "for a, b in [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]: " mean? Why does it print me this?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I got confused with some for loop statement. I can't figure out what exactly does it do.

```py
for a, b in [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]:
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

I coudn't expect any output.

The output is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: `tuple unpacking` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python

Answer (score 3):

It's tuple unpacking, just like in an assignment statement. It's a shorter way of writing

```
for t in [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)]:
    a, b = t
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Instead of assigning each tuple to `t`, then unpacking `t` into `a` and `b`, each tuple is unpacked directly to `a` and `b` by the `for` loop.

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you.  So why does "for a, b in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]: print(a); print(b)" throw an exception?
"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: For the same reason `a, b = 0` would throw the same error. You can't extract multiple items from the *iterable* in a `for` loop, and the new example is a list of ints, not a list of (iterable) tuples.

Answer (score 0):

This means:

step 1: `a, b = (0, 1)`, so `print(a)` will produce `0` and `print(b)` will produce `1`.

step 2: `a, b = (2, 3)`, so `print(a)` will produce `2` and `print(b)` will produce `3`.

step 3: `a, b = (4, 5)`, so `print(a)` will produce `4` and `print(b)` will produce `5`.